# preg_match in PHP for "&$"

Tags: php, string, preg-match, special-characters, delimiter

I am trying to implement preg_match for string containing special characters : "&$".

The code that i am using :

```
$f = fopen($path,"r");

while($lines = fgets($f))
{
    if(preg_match("/\&\$/",trim($lines),$matches))
    {
        echo "Yes<br>";
    }
}
```

I have already tried preg_match("/&\$/",$lines,$matches)

I am getting nothing as a result. (The file related to "$path" that i am using contains 2 lines containing "&$").

Plz help !!

Comment: If you are looking for a fixed string, don't use `preg_match`, use `strpos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a dollar expression within the double-quoted pattern.

The following works for me:

```
if(preg_match('/&\$/',trim($lines),$matches))
```

Check this existing question on the difference between single and double quotes:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thank You for providing the link related to the single and double quoted strings. This helped me a lot.